# Django admin on delete image (bug or error)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

After the image was deleted, I needed to remove it from filesystem.
I used signal for this.
It works well until I found some strange behaviour.
If in django admin I select another file (so, I change image file) and simultaneously choose delete image then image is not removed from filesystem/ It looks like django tries to delete the file that is in POST data.

Is there any way to delete old file?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to delete the old image when you replace an image in Django admin.

For this a delete signal will not help since the model instance is never deleted but only a single attribute is changed. For this you need a way to figure out if the model instance is dirty (any fields have changed) when saving.

You can use [django-dirtyfields](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dirtyfields/) to do this.

```
class FooModel(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='...')
    ...

def changeremove(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_dirty():
        name = 'image'
        new = getattr(instance, name)
        old = instance.get_dirty_fields().get(name, None)
        if old:
            old.delete(save=False)
            setattr(instance, name, new)

post_save.connect(changeremove, sender=FooModel)
```

Comment: No. It works fine if image is only changed. But if I'm changing file and simultaneously tick delete checkbox, then image is not removed.

Comment: Are you using it as an admin inline then?